# How to connect to a plugin route on routes.php file CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I have a plugin named Manager. I want to map route on /login to the index action of Dashboard Controller on plugin. Something like this:

```
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin => 'manager'));
```

How can I achieve this on Cakephp 2.2?

thanks

Comment: My example worked for me... I don't know why it's not working while ago... sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Once a plugin has been installed in `/app/Plugin`, you can access it at the URL `/plugin_name/controller_name/action`. In your Manager plugin example, you'd access DashboardController at `/manager/dashboard`.

Have you tries using Plugin Syntax, like:

```
Router::connect('/login', 
    array('controller' => 'Manager.dashboard', 'action' => 'index')
);
```

Using the `'plugin'` key in the `$options` array should also do the job:

```
Router::connect('/login', 
    array('plugin' => 'manager','controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If use plugin like 'users plugin' try in plugin's routes file (routes.php)